# Positioning an absolute div inside overflow-x: auto

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to position an `absolute` `div` in a container using `overflow-x: auto`

In very short the scenario is this one:

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto">
    <div style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute">
            I'm not absolute :(
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

---

I did a minimal example using tailwindcss https://jsfiddle.net/fhp64ztv/2/

Right now, I have two results:

- Using `overflow-y: visible` *(or nothing)* and I get the expected visual, but I cannot scroll inside the container/navbar.
  [image]
- Using `overflow-y: auto` I can scroll inside the container/navbar but don't get the expected visual.
  [image]

---

**Edit** Since I have to add a stack snippet:

```html
<nav class="nav bg-white flex items-center shadow justify-between flex-wrap p-6 sticky top-0 z-10">
    <div class="nav-content w-full flex-grow max-h-screen">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item block">Docs</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item block">Examples</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item block"> Blog</a>
        <div class="nav-item dropdown relative mt-4">
            <button class="text-indigo-500 inline-block">
                Profile
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-items bg-white border absolute left-auto mt-2 py-2 z-50">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item block px-4 py-2">Account settings</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item block px-4 py-2">Support</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item block px-4 py-2">Sign out</a>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</nav>
```

```css
.nav-content {
  /* I want it to look like this */
  /*overflow-y: visible;  */

  /* But I need this to scroll in the navbar */
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: What you need is a bit complex and will need some javascript. However what you can do is open the menu towards UP and all your issues will be solved :) without any javascript.  Is that something you consider?

Comment: @Aslam towards up could be a solution but, in my opinion, it's counter intuitive. I'm not against a bit of javascript to fix that, but I'm not sure what it should do.

Comment: Try `nav.nav { overflow-y: auto; }` and removing the overflow options from `.nav-content`

Comment: @fnostro It doesn't change anything. I guess it's because the dropdown is still a children of  `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: Can you clarify? You have a situation where the expected visual conflicts with the necessity of scrolling. The only reason to scroll is to bring the hidden portions into view, but your expected visual shows the menu system in its entirety, so why is there a need to scroll?  Seems like what you want is to maybe adjust the `z-index` rather than `overflow`

Comment: @fnostro Because when the menu is bigger than the screen, the scroll taken is the one from the page since the menu is `sticky` and you have to scroll the entire page to go down the menu. `z-index` has no effect there (at least on firefox). At the moment I resolved this with an accordion instead of the dropdown when the screen hit the breakpoint. I would still be interested to know how to solve this though.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fnostro/tc4Lr5fj/2/) closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: @fnostro Thanks, but that's not visually what I'm looking for (the dropdown is inside the menu, I want it outside). This is kind of how I resolved it when I said "I resolved this with an accordion". Someone told me, what I'm trying to do is not possible at the moment with CSS. Apparently it would be a limitation with how overflow and absolute elements work.